# Laravel - Initial cookie value always persisting?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I have a cookie set called 'country', set to whatever country the user selects (defaulted to USA).  If the user changes it, I call `Cookie::queue('country', $country,  9999999);`.

Currently in Firefox for some users, when I queue a new cookie (or Cookie::make in App::after like below:

```
App::after(function($request, $response) use ($country)
            {
                $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('country', $country, 99999));
            });
```

it just gets reset back to the previous value. Nothing is being echoed before the view. I can only reproduce it in FireFox (And not in Private mode, there it works fine).

Has anyone seen this issue and if so how to remedy?

As a side note, if I echo a comment at the end of my view  I get the correct country, however, on refresh that value is not changed.  There's only been a handful of customers to complain about this.